# Is there a way to completely block external access to GSuite?

Tags: gmail, security, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I want to force my users to use the gmail web interface for everything. I.e. block them from being able to add their accounts to email clients/phones etc, block sending via SMTP server etc.

How would I go about this? I've already disabled IMAP/POP. Anything else I should be looking at doing? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several settings that you could manage to control how your users access Gmail for your organization

From [Tailor Gmail settings for your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2786758?hl=en)

> ## Learn about each setting
>
> ### End user access settings
>
> To access these settings from the Admin console home page, go to Apps
>   G Suite > Settings for Gmail > End User Access.
>
> - POP and IMAP access—Enable or disable POP and IMAP access for users.
> - G Suite​ Sync—Enable G Suite Sync for Microsoft® Outlook®.
> - Automatic forwarding—Prevent users from automatically forwarding incoming messages to another address.
> - Image URL proxy whitelist—Create and maintain a whitelist of internal URLs that bypasses proxy protection. Can only be configured
>     at the top-level organization and applies to all organizations.
> - Gmail Offline Chrome plugin —Enable Gmail Offline for users.
> - Allow per-user outbound gateways—Allow users to send mail through an external SMTP server.
> - Unintended external reply warning—Warn users when replying to a message with external recipients not in their contacts.

Besides the above there are other settings that you should check like accessing  G Suite data from mobile devices.